# Static files cannot be loaded nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have declared a static path to the static files such as CSS and javascript files. where there is a single URL path the static files are retrieved successfully but when I add a subpath they are not accessible.

Folders location

```
/static/css
/static/js
```

in HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="css/progress.less" type="text/css">
```

in server.js

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + ""));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/static"));
app.use('/static', express.static('/static/'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```

in a single path, they are accessible for example

```
localhost:4000/css/style.css
```

but in a url like this

```
localhost:4000/services/construction/css/style.css
```

This throw an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use `express.static` once. Don't confuse matters by giving multiple URLs to all your static files.

You said `localhost:4000/css/style.css` works, so go with the invocation which makes that URL work:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/static"));
```

Then, change your HTML to point to **that** URL all the time.

> ```
> <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="css/progress.less" type="text/css">
> ```

This is a *path relative URL*. It will drop everything off the last `/` in the path and keep everything before and including that `/`.

So depending on where the HTML document is, you'll be referencing a different URL for the stylesheet.

Use an **absolute path** instead. Start the URL with a `/`:

```
href="/css/progress.less"
```

Answer (score 0):

have you try to use `app.use(express.static('static'));`